# Need help understanding pushouts with an example.

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

> Say $f:\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z}$ and $g:\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/c\mathbb{Z}$ are homomorphisms. When can the pushout $W$ be cyclic?

I don't know where to begin to answer this. I can't think of anything besides that for $f,g$ to be well defined, it must be that $c$ and $b$ have to divide $a$. But then I still don't know if $W$ is going to be cyclic,or not.

Also, how would one go about finding $W$ explicitly, given some fixed integers, say, $a=12,b=6,c=4 \,$?

Comment: You should start from making explicit what this pushout is. For $R$-modules (or in any abelian category), to find the pushout of $f\colon N\to M_1$ and $g\colon N\to M_2$, you should calculate the cokernel of the morphism

\begin{align*}
{f\choose -g}\colon N & \to M_1\oplus M_2,\\
n & \mapsto (f (n), 0) - (0, g(n)).
\end{align*}

That is, you take the quotient of $M_1 \oplus M_2$ by the submodule
$$\{ (f (n), 0) - (0, g(n)) \mid n\in N \}.$$

To see it, just check that the universal property of $\operatorname{coker} {f\choose -g}$ corresponds to the universal property of pushout.

Comment: "For $f$, $g$ to be well defined, it must be that $c$ and $b$ have to divide a $a$." — no, for $f$ and $g$ to be well defined, you should impose conditions on $f$ and $g$. If $(a,b) = 1$, then you still get one legitimate homomorphism $f\colon \mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z}$ :-)

Comment: @Alejo, yes, the zero map. So it just needs to be mentioned that $f,g$ are non-trivial. And all this combines to guarantee $W$ is cyclic? I will try to do the computations as you suggested above.

Comment: @Alejo I tried to do the calculations but it's all still very confusing and I'm not sure what we're supposed to be doing. Also, we haven't studied the universal property of cokernel.

Comment: This all means that to calculate the pushout of $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon A\to C$, you should take the direct sum $B\oplus C$ and quotient it by the subgroup $\{ (f (a), -g(a)) \mid a \in A \}$.